# SSIS Packages get stuck in SQL Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, sql-server-agent

We run about a dozen scheduled SQL Agent jobs which run SSIS packages.

Intermittently, every scheduled job will get stuck in a running state. i.e. we'll arrive in the morning and notice that there's a bunch of jobs still running. Sometimes we don't actually notice it for days. Further investigation seems to indicate that the package never starts:

- DTEXEC process has 0 or very little CPU time
- No logging or data activity occurs in the database

There is no loss of functionality in the actual database server, we don't notice anything (except stale data) until we check SQL Agent status, or start a job and it doesn't finish

We can stop and restart the jobs and they simply get stuck again
SQL Commands and CMDEXEC steps still work fine.

One job's first step copies a file with XCOPY then runs a package. The job completes the file copy then gets stuck on the package

There are a few customisations

- Most packages are run from a master package, but the issue occurs for standalone packages
- We have a custom built tool which queries and starts jobs via T-SQL but this is not in use
- We use a framework called BIPA for our logging

Looking in the SQL Server logs, there seem to be a lot of AD type windows authentication errors. However these happen all the time regardless of the SQL Agent issue

We don't use the SSIS service. Packages are run from the file system using the SSIS step.

I can't think of anything further to troubleshoot at this stage. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

If you're interested I narrowed this down to our SSIS framework which is called 'BIPA'. I deleted the BIPA logging addin and we no longer have this problem. Based on the .net wait's happening in SSIS I believe it just couldn't instantiate the provider somehow. Why it only does this at night I don't know.

Strange thing is it does run fine when run interactively from DTEXEC (i.e. in a batch file) but won't run in SQL Agent (as a different user of course)

Comment: what is the account used by these sql agent jobs to execute those ssis packages?

Comment: we had something similar to  you're above issue and we found that jobs running were using LOCAL account to run and were not able to access the required path per package reqrm's. Changed the account to a different account with proper privileges to execute the package. Can you check on this?

Comment: The thing is they run fine under the same service account the whole time. They just intermittently stop. I would expect some kind of error if there was a security issue, but instead they just don't start

Comment: Did you noticed something in trace or sql error logs?

Comment: In SQL Profiler trace there is no activity. In the SQL Error logs there are a lot of errors saying the service account cannot log into its default database. This doesn't make any sense though - if the service account suddenly couldn't log in to a database the package would return an error, not just stop.

Comment: Check the default database setting for your service account. If you correct it you can get rid of useless messages. Likely the default database is not the database you are actually updating.

Comment: The default database is fine. The service account is sysadm so there's no reason it can't get into the DB. I don't understand the error - a sysadm will never be unable to log into any database

Comment: The other thing is we have a DEV and TEST SQL instance on the same box and they seem to hang at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a hiccup communicating with AD since all the instances go squirrelly around the same time. Anything of interest in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes, I have my suspicions about AD, but.... I didn't mention this... we also have a PROD instance which seems to be behave. I don't think its had this problem. There are a a LOT of factors going into this one, and I don't expect I'll be able to find a solution here, just suggestions. @bilinkc, have you ever had issues with this 'certificate revocation' issue? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic522133-148-1.aspx.  It seems this can cause a delayed start but not a total hang (for days)

Comment: OK it happened again. I fire up Process Explorer and took a look at the DTExec process (which is doing nothing). It had 10 threads all in various wait states. There were 6 mscorwks.CreateApplicationContext threads in state Wait_UserRequest. This is not my area of expertise and I don't think it's telling me anything new.

Comment: If you're interested I narrowed this down to our SSIS framework which is called 'BIPA'. I deleted the BIPA logging add in and we no longer have this problem. Based on the .net wait's happening in SSIS I believe it just couldn't instantiate the provider somehow. Why it only does this at night I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should debug SSIS package in visual studio, if you have solution file.

I got this situation couple of month before, when I execute the package they stuck on the data flow. 
I had resolved my problem by removing the transaction script from the package. Because I importing bulk of data and transaction create kind of deadlock situation....

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thankyou Aishwary but the packages run fine 95% of the time, and when they stop, they all stop (including for example backup plan packages which I didn't develop). I don't have any transactions in any package. If this was the case I would see some indication of database activity but there is none.